# Generating random numbers as damage numbers in a fight simulation using a for loop

Tags: c#, random

I am attempting to create a fighting simulation where a random number is generated between 50 and 100 in a for loop. This random number is then subtracted from one of the fighters max HP and then vice versa as it loops and until one of the fighters health reach 0.

I currently have this and have no clue what to do to fix it and is there an easier loop to use?

```
for(int x = 0; x < fighter1.hp || x < fighter2.hp; x++)
        {
            damage.Next(50, 100); //number generator
            Console.WriteLine(fighter1.name + " dealt " + damage + " damage to " 
                                        + fighter2.name);
        }
```

It's currently printing this:

```
Khal Drogo dealt System.Random damage to Jon Snow
Khal Drogo dealt System.Random damage to Jon Snow
Khal Drogo dealt System.Random damage to Jon Snow
Khal Drogo dealt System.Random damage to Jon Snow
Khal Drogo dealt System.Random damage to Jon Snow
Khal Drogo dealt System.Random damage to Jon Snow
```

Comment: _" have no clue what to do to fix it"_ - you forgot to explain what's broken about it.

Comment: @Fildor yeah my bad, I just uploaded a screenshot of the output

Comment: oh, I see. You are outputting the result of "toString" of the Random object. You need to store the result of the `Next` call in a variable to output the value. Then you need to actually subtract it from the players' hp.

Comment: As an aside, this will evenly spread the damage option across the whole range. Typically games operate using multiple "dice". This changes the spread, where damage _can_ fall across the entire range, but it's weighted to be more likely/common for the damage value to be somewhere near of the middle of the possible range, and much rarer to be near the extremes of the range. For example, you might run a roll of 5D10. This has only 45 possible values (5 1's to 5 10's), but the average and typical rolls will be closer to 27/28.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn While I agree with you, that feels like "earn your A+" given OP is a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never use the value that your RNG produces. Try something like

```
for(int x = 0; fighter1.hp > 0 && fighter2.hp > 0; x++)
{
   var damageDone = damage.Next(50, 100);
   fighter2.hp -= damageDone; // Your logic to apply damage goes here
   Console.WriteLine(fighter1.name + " dealt " + damageDone + " damage to " + fighter2.name);
}
```

Comment: That' s still not quite right. Check the loop's parameters.

Comment: @Fildor Since the OP doesn't contain any hint how the damage is to be distributed between the two fighters, I only gave an example of how to use the value and used the comment to convey this. Besides that you're of course right.

Comment: Fair enough. It just won't quit when one of the hp reach 0 ...

Comment: @Fildor Yah that's a mistake on my part, it should be as long as fighter's hp is > 0 in the parameters.

Comment: @Fildor Ah, I missed that. I've changed the condition. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @BillTür yeah you made me realize I never stored the RNG lol, thanks for this. Now I just need to figure out how to keep iterating until one of the fighters reach 0.

Comment: @BbOii I've changed the condition in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like homework to me.
Anyway....

```
for (int x = 0; fighter1.hp > 0 && fighter2.hp > 0; x++) // we are doing things in cycle while both fighters have more than 0 hp (until one of them is below or equal zero)
{
    var damageDone = damage.Next(50, 100); // getting the value of damage (radnom 50-100)
    // now we have to substract the damage done

    // we will use x to choose fighter
    if(x % 2 == 1) // if the number x is odd
    {
        // we will damage the second fighter
        fighter2.hp -= damageDone; // substract HP (like fighter2.hp = fighter2.hp - damageDone)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} dealt {1} damage to {2}", fighter1.name, damageDone, fighter2.name);
    }
    else // if the number x is even
    {
        // we will damage the first fighter
        fighter1.hp -= damageDone; // substract HP
        Console.WriteLine("{0} dealt {1} damage to {2}", fighter2.name, damageDone, fighter1.name)
    }
}
```

The code can be optimized and may not work on first try, but i guess the homework is done.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are invoking `Next()` method on the `Random` object but not storing the return value, which prevents you from using it to do anything.  Furthermore, when you are printing your output, you're actually printing the `Random` object, which is why you're seeing System.Random, because that is how the object identifies itself via the `ToString()` function.

What you'll need to do is save the output from the `Next()` call and then use *that* in your output, and for any future processing:

```
for(int x = 0; x < fighter1.hp || x < fighter2.hp; x++)
{
    var damageDealt = damage.Next(50, 100); //number generator
    Console.WriteLine(fighter1.name + " dealt " + damageDealt + " damage to " 
                                        + fighter2.name);

    // additional logic here
}
```